# Only some Laravel routes in controller work

Tags: php, laravel, rest, routes

I'm using Laravel as a RestAPI with React on the front end. The GET route works, but within the same controller, the PUT and DELETE routes don't.

Here are the routes as specified in `api.php`. Other (not listed) routes within this file work too.

```
// works
Route::get('unapproved', [
  'uses' => 'AdminController@indexEvents',
  'middleware' =>'auth.jwt'
]);
// doesn't work (404 error)
Route::put('unapproved/${id}', [
  'uses' => 'AdminController@approveEvent',
  'middleware' =>'auth.jwt'
]);
// doesn't work (404 error)
Route::delete('unapproved/${id}', [
  'uses' => 'AdminController@deleteEvent',
  'middleware' =>'auth.jwt'
]);
```

Here is `AdminController.php`. There are a few other working controllers I didn't list.

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
  // works
  public function indexEvents() // works
  {
    return Event::where('approved', 0)->get();
  }
  // not recognized by api.php
  public function approveEvent(Request $request, $id)
  {
    echo $request; // for testing purposes
  }
  // not recognized by api.php
  public function deleteEvent()
  {
    $event = Event::find($id);
    $event->delete();
    return response()->json(null, 204);
  }
}
```

API requests are coming from `auth.js` where other requests work:

```
// works
getEvents: (token) => {
  const url = `api/unapproved?token=${token}`
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => axios.get(url)
    .then(res => resolve(res.data))
    .catch(err => reject(err)) )
},
// doesn't work
approveEvent: (token, event, id) => {
  const url = `api/unapproved/${id}?token=${token}`
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => axios.put(url, event)
    .then(res => resolve(res.data))
    .catch(err => reject(err)) )
},
// doesn't work
deleteEvent: (token, id) => {
  const url = `api/unapproved/${id}?token=${token}`
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => axios.delete(url)
    .then(res => resolve(res.data))
    .catch(err => reject(err)) )
},
```

The the `AuthController.php` must accessible from `api.php` because the GET route works, but the two PUT and DELETE routes I listed aren't working. The working routes use the same middleware, and I'm getting 404 errors, not authentication errors.

I've console.logged in `api.js` the URLS each route is going to and they match what is expected. Also, the routes and their corresponding functions are based off other parts of the site that work--the only difference being variables.

Any reason why it would recognize some routes that use functions within a controller, but not other routes that point to different functions within the same controller?

System info: Laravel 5.4, Php 5.6, running locally with Apache on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes within Laravel are incorrect, you need to remove the `$` before the bindings:

```
// doesn't work (404 error)
Route::put('unapproved/{id}', [
  'uses' => 'AdminController@approveEvent',
  'middleware' =>'auth.jwt'
]);
// doesn't work (404 error)
Route::delete('unapproved/{id}', [
  'uses' => 'AdminController@deleteEvent',
  'middleware' =>'auth.jwt'
]);
```

You also will want to pass the `id` to `deleteEvent` method.

I would also take a look at [implicit bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#implicit-binding) which could automatically resolve your `Events`.

Comment: I just did a small test with $ in my routes and they work just fine. The routes in the javascript are also defined with a $ in them.

Comment: strange the ${id} worked in some places but not others.....but this worked!